# installing an older version of package in ubuntu 18

Tags: apt, 18.04, repository

So in the global ubuntu APT repos, a package version can be deprecated quite often.

For example, yesterday I was able to install `apt install docker.io=x.y.z`, and today I am getting `E: Version 'x.y.z' for 'docker.io' was not found` - as now the latest version is `x.y.z-1`.

The default apt repos in the sources.list are:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

Is there a global repo which holds packages' versions when they are deprecated?

I am trying to avoid having a local APT cache which will hold old versions for me. I assumed those deprecated versions go to some other repo?

Comment: Do not invent your own package versions, simply visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/docker.io to know correct version number (20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3).

Comment: Off course this isn’t a real version, I used it as example.. but to use real version, if I have “install docker.io= 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3)”, it can break any day , as like I said they deprecate versions quite often. And docker.io is just an example, this happens for a lot of packages